# Read a csv file in and calculate the difference between values in order to make a pie chart

Tags: c#, csv, pie-chart

I making an application for work to log what people are doing with their time. (ie Available, Busy, On-Site, Returning to Site, Quick Break, Lunch Break).

What happens is that when the user click on a button, it writes their username to a file and then a comma and then the time in hours, minutes and seconds. For example:

```
John,Available,10:10:26
Dave,Available,10:15:40
Steve,Available,10:44:14
John,Busy,12:13:28
Steve,QuickBreak,12:15:25
John,Available,12:18:03
Dave,Busy,12:18:03
```

I have worked out how display only the status update of a user and then populate into a label with this:

```
private void btnShowUser_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string SelectedUser = lstSelectUser.GetItemText(lstSelectUser.SelectedItem);
            List<string> resLines = new List<string>();
            var lines = File.ReadLines(Filepath);
            foreach (var line in lines)
            {
                var res = line.Split(new char[] { ',' });
                //or name to search 
                if (res[0] == SelectedUser)
                {
                    resLines.Add(res[1] + " " + res[2] + " " + res[3]);
                }
            }
            //to get the output  
            foreach (var line in resLines)
            {
                lblUserData.Text += (line) + System.Environment.NewLine;
            }
        }
```

What I would like to do if possible, is work out the time difference that each user spends in and then use this to populate a Pie Graph in a chart so that it can show the size of each segment in the pie graph that the user spends in each status. So in my code, could I somehow calculate the sum total time that the user spends in each status and create a pie chart on this? I had an idea about reading each line in and then checking the status and working out the change from each status and then adding this to a variable to populate the pie graph, but cant figure this out.. any help would be appreciated greatly! Thanks.

Comment: First off I'd suggest you use a library for working with CSV files so you avoid all the pitfalls you can run into (one example among others is [CsvHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/)). Two questions for you: what happens when the user is done for the day? How do you measure the time of the last status?

Comment: You want to show a pie chart for a single user, right? For the SelectedUser? First of all you should introduce an `enum` e.g., `UserState` for all the possible user states. Then create a `Record` class that has a `UserState:UserState`, a `StateBegin:DateTime`, `StateDuration:TimeSpan`  and a `Name:String` property.

Comment: Use [`Enum.TryParse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.tryparse?view=netcore-3.1) to convert the status string  from the file to a `UserState` enum value. Use [`DateTime.TryParse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparse?view=netcore-3.1) to convert the timestamp (you should really save the date too). Use these values to initialize a new `Record`.

Comment: Use [`DateTime.Subtract`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.subtract?view=netcore-3.1#System_DateTime_Subtract_System_DateTime_) to calculate the time duration (`TimeSpan`) between two `Record.StateBegin` (of the same `Record.Name`) and set the `Record.StateDuration` property to the resulting [`TimeSpan`.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan?view=netcore-3.1).

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by summarizing each employees duration in a given status, preferably the CSV file has column headers and then it's possible to use [Schema.ini](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/microsoft/schema-ini-file-text-file-driver?view=sql-server-ver15) and query the data using `ODBC text driver`, minimum reproducible example:

**sampledata.csv:**

```
Name,Status,Time
John,Available,10:10:26
Dave,Available,10:15:40
Steve,Available,10:44:14
John,Busy,12:13:28
Steve,QuickBreak,12:15:25
John,Available,12:18:03
Dave,Busy,12:18:03
Steve,Busy,12:28:16
John,Offline,17:00:00
Dave,Offline,17:00:00
Steve,Offline,17:00:00
```

**Schema.ini:**

```
[sampledata.csv]
Format=CSVDelimited
ColNameHeader=True
Col1 = "Name" Text
Col2 = "Status" Text
Col3 = "TimeStamp" DateTime
```

**Employee class and Status Enum:**

```
class Employee
{
    public static List<Employee> Employees { get; private set; } = new List<Employee>();
    public string Name { get; }
    public StatusEnum Status { get; }
    public DateTime TimeStamp { get; }
    public TimeSpan Duration { get; private set; }
            

    public Employee(string name, StatusEnum status, DateTime time)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Status = status;
        this.TimeStamp = time;
        Employees.Add(this);
    }

    public static Dictionary<string, double> GetEmployeeStatusSummary(Employee employee)
    {
        var dict = new Dictionary<string, double>();
        foreach (var emp in Employees.Where(e => e.Name == employee.Name))
        {
            if (dict.ContainsKey(emp.Status.ToString()))
            {
                dict[emp.Status.ToString()] += emp.Duration.TotalMinutes;
            }
            else
            {
                dict.Add(emp.Status.ToString(), emp.Duration.TotalMinutes);
            }
        }
        return dict;
    }

    public static void UpdateAllEmployeesDuration()
    {
        Employees = Employees.OrderBy(e => e.Name).ThenBy(e => e.TimeStamp).ToList();
        TimeSpan duration;
        for (int i = 0; i < Employees.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            if (Employees[i].Name == Employees[i + 1].Name)
            {
                duration = Employees[i + 1].TimeStamp - Employees[i].TimeStamp;
                Employees[i].Duration = duration;
            }
        }
    }

    override public string ToString()
    {
        return this.Name;
    }
}

enum StatusEnum
{
    Available,
    Busy,
    QuickBreak,
    Break,
    Offline
}
```

Then the `Form` with the pie chart, a refresh button triggers the flow --> querying the CSV file, updating the drop down with employee names and clearing the chart, useful if the CSV file updates often and users want to see fresh data.
The `ComboBox` event `SelectedIndexChanged` will update the chart to display data of the selected employee.

```
private void btn_Refresh_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var csvPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);
    var connStr = "Driver={Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt; *.csv)}; Extensions=asc,csv,tab,txt; Dbq=";
    var dt = new DataTable();

    using (var conn = new OdbcConnection(connStr + csvPath))
    using (var odba = new OdbcDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM sampledata.csv", conn))
    {
        odba.Fill(dt);
    }

    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        var name = row[nameof(Employee.Name)].ToString();
        Enum.TryParse(row[nameof(Employee.Status)].ToString(), out StatusEnum status);
        var duration = (DateTime)row[nameof(Employee.TimeStamp)];
        new Employee(name, status, duration);
    }
    Employee.UpdateAllEmployeesDuration();

    this.chart_Pie.Series.Clear();
    this.cbx_Names.DataSource = Employee.Employees.GroupBy(emp => emp.Name)
                                                    .Select(g => g.First())
                                                    .ToList();
}

private void cbx_Names_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var employee = (Employee)cbx_Names.SelectedItem;
            
    if (this.chart_Pie.Series.IsUniqueName(employee.Name) == false)
    {
        foreach (var series in this.chart_Pie.Series)
        {
            if (series.Name.Equals(employee.Name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                series.Enabled = true;
            }
            else
            {
                series.Enabled = false;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        foreach (var ser in this.chart_Pie.Series)
        {
            ser.Enabled = false;
        }
        var points = Employee.GetEmployeeStatusSummary(employee);
        var series = new Series(employee.Name);
        series.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Pie;
        this.chart_Pie.Series.Add(series);
        this.chart_Pie.Series[employee.Name].Points.DataBindXY(points.Keys, points.Values);
    }
}
```

Finally the result:

[image]